# How can I split a list of coordinates that output from a function?

Tags: excel, data-manipulation

From python, I wrote multiple lists of coordinates (varying length) in the form `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)]` to rows in Excel, and I would like to split them into however many columns needed to have one set per column in each list's respective row: `x1,y1 | x2,y2 | ... | xn,yn`. If I go directly to Text to Columns, I am unable to choose multiple delimiters (to get rid of the square brackets, etc), so I decided to do some processing first:

I now have

```
=MID(B2, 2, LEN(B2)-2)
(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)
```

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C2," ", "")
(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...,(xn,yn)
```

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D2, "),(", ");(")
(x1,y1);(x2,y2);...;(xn,yn)
```

So I could theoretically now use Text to Columns and use `;` as a delimiter. However, when I try to do that it instead attempts to split the *formula* in that cell instead of the text produced by the formula:
[splitting cell by semicolon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yifNE.png)

Does anyone know a way that I can use the text itself, or better yet, an eaiser way of processing the data overall? Thanks!

Comment: "From Python, I wrote multiple lists ... to rows in Excel". How exactly did you do that? It might be worth looking at how you are doing the writing, as it will be easier to manipulate the data in Python before writing.

Comment: In python, I had a few similar dictionaries where the keys map to various datatypes, one of which is a list of geographical coordinates. I then converted the dictionaries to a pandas dataframe (key as column title, value as the entry), and wrote to excel. So, for example, the entry under column "Points" and row "Game 5" is a list of all the geographical points from that specific game.

Comment: Also to clarify, the number of coordinate pairs changes with each game. It may be anywhere from 10 to 50 or more, so making each point a separate entry in the dataframe would be problematic, since some rows would be longer than others.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the output to look?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the starting DataFrame could look something like this:

```
                                         Points
Game1                  [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
Game2                         [(7, 8), (9, 10)]
Game3  [(11, 12), (13, 14), (15, 16), (17, 18)]
```

DataFrames can handle rows of different lengths:

```
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame([
                       [[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]],
                       [[(7,8),(9,10)]],
                       [[(11,12),(13,14),(15,16),(17,18)]] ],
                       index=['Game1','Game2','Game3'],
                       columns=['Points'])

df = pd.DataFrame( data=[['{0:},{1:}'.format(a,b) for a,b in r] 
                             for r in input_df['Points'].tolist()],
                   index=input_df.index  )

df.to_excel('c:\\somepath\\coords.xlsx',header=False)
```

The resulting Excel sheet looks like this:

[image]